# Plot datetime x axis with irregular intervals

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot data for custom date range . So my data set is like every day from 8 a.m. to 5 p.m. I need to plot this time ranges for 5 days. How can i do that so that i dont get the other time range apart from the above mentioned. I tried plotting using x locator but it shows the data in full time range.

tried setting x locator didn't work

Comment: Hi @Dhruv! Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you be able to post the code you've used so far that shows the full time range? That'll help us work out how to help.

Comment: The matplotlib documentation has [a section "skip-dates-where-there-is-no-data"](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#skip-dates-where-there-is-no-data). You may want to show (using code, [mcve]) in how far that doesn't help here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
x= pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime( 2019, 7, 8, 8, 0,0 ), freq='10min',end=datetime.datetime ( 2019, 7, 12, 17, 0 ,0))
start = datetime.time(8, 0, 0)
end = datetime.time(17, 0, 0)

def time_in_range(start, end, x):
    """Return true if x is in the range [start, end]"""
    if start <= end:
        return start <= x <= end
    else:
        return start <= x or x <= end   

t= [i.to_datetime() for i in x if time_in_range(start,end,i.to_datetime().time())]



df=pd.DataFrame({'d':d,'t':t})
df=df.set_index('t')
fig,axes = plt.subplots()
axes.xaxis_date()
axes.bar(mdates.date2num(list(df.index)),df['d'],align='center',width=0.006,color='pink')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
xformatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y:%H:%M')
xlocator = mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(8,17,2))
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(xlocator)
plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformatter)
plt.show()
```

Comment: in the above code d can be any random data of len 275